# What does 'the stock of the cars on the road' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean ***the numbers of the cars*** on the road?

> In the fall of 2009, the National Highway Transportation Safety Agency
> (NHTSA) received several dozen complaints per month about Toyota cars
> speeding out of control. The rate of complaint was not that different
> from the rates of complaint for other car companies. Then, in November
> of 2009, Toyota recalled 3.8 million vehicles to check for sticking
> gas pedals. By February, the complaint rate had risen from several
> dozen per month to over 1,500 per month of alleged cases of unintended
> acceleration. Attention turned to the electronic throttle. Clearly,
> what changed was not the actual condition of cars — the ***stock*** of
> Toyotas on the road in February of 2010 was not that different from
> November of 2009. What changed was car owners’ awareness as a result
> of the headlines surrounding the recall. Acceleration problems,
> whether real or illusory, that escaped notice before November 2009
> became causes for worry and a trip to the dealer. Later, the NHTSA
> examined a number of engine data recorders from accidents where the
> driver claimed to have experienced acceleration despite applying the
> brakes. In all cases, the data recorders showed that the brakes were
> not applied. In April 2011, the US Department of Transportation
> announced that a 10-month investigation of the electronic throttle
> showed no problems.

[Introductory Statistics and Analytics: A Resampling Perspective](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=7CUhBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=Later,%20the%20NHTSA%20examined%20a%20number%20of%20engine%20data%20recorders%20from%20accidents%20where%20the%20driver%20claimed%20to%20have%20experienced%20acceleration%20despite%20applying%20the%20brakes.%20In%20all%20cases,%20the%20data%20recorders%20showed%20that%20the%20brakes%20were%20not%20applied.&source=bl&ots=NRH746lf21&sig=ACfU3U1-1diTbpSMJlwSTfe9AThYfFeVBA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg7oPC4bjwAhXIZt4KHYGBBs4Q6AEwAHoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=Later%2C%20the%20NHTSA%20examined%20a%20number%20of%20engine%20data%20recorders%20from%20accidents%20where%20the%20driver%20claimed%20to%20have%20experienced%20acceleration%20despite%20applying%20the%20brakes.%20In%20all%20cases%2C%20the%20data%20recorders%20showed%20that%20the%20brakes%20were%20not%20applied.&f=false)

Comment: _stock_  here means the total number of cars on the road.

Answer (score 1):

It means the group of cars in that category.
If you go to a store they have a **stock** of a certain item available in the store, 27 jars of tomato sauce. The 27 jars are the stock of tomato sauce.

So the stock of cars having this problem are the Toyotas from some period of production or with some equipment characteristics. You could say,

'The stock of cars with electronic throttles produced between date1 and date 2 at a  particular plant.'

'The stock of cars produced between date1 and date 2.'